# MVC 4 - Cookie already expired on ActionExecutingContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, filter

I'm a little lost on this and I can't find a solution.

I'm creating a Filter using below code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class SessionFilter :System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
```

And I'm validating if a cookie exist, is null or blank or expired with below code:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] == null ||
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value) ||
    (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires < DateTime.Now &&
    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires != new DateTime()))
                   {
```

But cookie is already expired in this section even when the value for expiration is set for one day after:

```
private void SetAuthenticationCookie(String username, String MyValue)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.ToUpper(), false);
    var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);
    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

    HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie", MyValue);
    newCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
}
```

Here is the configuration on Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/SignIn/" protection="All" timeout="1440" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="/" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
```

Thank you so much again.